# Convert TIFF to ECW in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, ecw

I intend to convert GeoTIFF file format into ECW file format in QGIS 3 on Windows 10 OS. However, "Save As Layer" doesn't list ECW file format. How to convert GeoTIFF file format into ECW file format in QGIS 3 on Windows 10 OS?

Comment: Please review questions about adding [ECW support to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecw+qgis). The process is operating system specific so please edit your question to include what OS you use and how you installed QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing ECW with the SDK 5.x libraries requires a license from Hexagon.
https://bynder.hexagon.com/m/5af86a8895f6696f/original/Hexagon_GSP_ERDAS_ECW_JP2_SDK_5_5_User_Guide.pdf. The license belongs to those without public price list

In summary:

• No license fee required:

- Desktop Read-Only Redistributable
- Mobile Read-Only Redistributable (local decoding restrictions apply)

• OEM licenses:

- Desktop Read-Write Redistributable
- Server Read-Only End-user
- Server Read-Only Redistributable
- Server Read-Write Redistributable

The license price will vary according to these characteristics. Please contact your local Hexagon's Geospatial
division sales representative to discuss your requirements or to request a quote.

However, paying the SDK license does not make QGIS to write ECW because it is built to use the read-only redistributable library. One option would be to buy a license for a standalone Hexagon GeoCompressor. Free options are to switch to JPEG 2000 with the free JP2OpenJPEG driver, or use JPEG compressed and tiled GeoTIFFs.

Comment: GDAL (so likely QGIS) supports Desktop ECW read/write (v4.x SDK or higher) if user has a valid license and set correctly in the ECW_ENCODE_KEY var. Still requires adding ECW support to GDAL (fairly easy on Windows, painful building from source on Linux, no idea about MacOS).