# Using GDAL to convert .TIFF to .ECW

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, ecw

I'm quite new to GDAL and coding in general. I'm trying to convert a whole bunch of TIFFs to ECW's,  but just wanted to test with one to start however I think I might be having problems with syntax. I run the below.bat file but nothing happens.

```
REM"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -of GTiff -of ECW 440554775.tif 440554775.ecw
```

Comment: This question: [Convert TIFF to ECW in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419273/convert-tiff-to-ecw-in-qgis?rq=1) may help.

Comment: What do you think the `REM` accomplishes here?

Comment: You have provided two outputformats `-of GTiff -of ECW`. That does not make sense.

Comment: I didn't realize REM was remarks, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DOS/batch `REM` is a comment or a **rem**ark. It means ignore everything on this line. So your `gdal_translate` command just gets skipped.

But even if you uncommented by removing the `REM`, your command would fail as the OSGeo4W ECW package `gdal-ecw` is [read-only](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-ecw):

> Write support for ECW and JPEG2000 via the ECW SDK is not available as part of OSGeo4W.